# How to load CSV file into DB using Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql

How do I load a CSV file into DB using Eclipse?
In the DB the first column is an account id but there is a different id in the database, which is an auto increment primary key.

Link to the dataset  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZEP57L_kWlZkCv51mfIb59Wbxzpna2Nr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *primary key autoincrement* means the database handles that one for you (on creation of a dataset, for an update, you need an existing id). What have you tried? Can you read the csv file? Do you have any objects representing a row in the csv file or a dataset in the database?

Comment: Hi bloodhound please refer [this website](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-load-csv-file-to-database/)

Comment: link to the designed db  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UNJ61nwJQiykpWzBw34q7HVen_bLY57X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looks like you basically just need one object (with a multitude of class attributes) and a query that inserts it as a new row.

Comment: please help me can u code it for this in eclipse and even the columns are also not matching

Comment: Sorry, this is not a coding service… And I also don't really get what you mean by *and even the columns are also not matching*. How can I know what's wrong with your columns?